# Options for saving and loading PDFs Forms/Data with a Angular/Node application?

Tags: node.js, angular, forms, pdf, angular-material

I have a Node/Angular application that is used by 15-20 people. Currently, the users fill out excel forms off line, and use the application to route them to the perspective business personal. I'm in the process of refactoring this application.

One of the asks, is to incorporate the excel forms into the application. I've started doing this by using the generic Material Forms.

While this process works, Material Forms are not as polished nor compact like a PDF form. My next adventure was to try and find a package that would allow me to load a PDF form in my Angular application, populate the PDF form data from a database, and also save the PDF form data bask to the database if there are changes.

Anyone have any suggestions OR a better way to incorporate multiple forms inside a node/angular application that is less clunky then material?

Answer (score 0):

When creating forms, there are two aspects to consider in my experience: first, its about the underlying data model. Second, it is about styling the data and making it easy for the user to input the correct data.

Angular Material Forms have their own unique way of styling form inputs. There are design philosophies (I'd call them) like material or bootstrap which implement rules on how to structure, use padding etc. with different design elements.

I would try to sketch out what a useful design looks like with tools like draw.io, figma etc. and look at different form layouts. "Just" adding a pdf-existent form in angular sounds not easily doable